# ElasticSearch: How do I aggregate whole string sentence by term of an analyzed field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a analyzed field, for instance, let's name it "motto". I want to full-text saerch "life" and aggregate them by count.

```
...
"query":{
    "term":{
        "motto":"life"
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "match_count": {
        "terms": "motto"
    }
}
...
```

The result I want it to be:

```
...
{
    ...
    "buckets": [
        {
            "key":"life is good",
            "doc_count":3
        }
    ]
    ...
}
...
```

The result actually it is:

```
{
    ...
    "buckets": [
        {
            "key": "life",
            "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
            "key": "good",
            "doc_count": 3
        },
        {
            "key": "is",
            "doc_count": 3
        }
    ]
    ...
}
```

How do I aggregate them as the way I want it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is to create a `not_analyzed` sub-field to the `motto` field, like this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_mapping -d '{
    "your_type": {
        "properties": {
            "motto": {
                "type": "string",
                "fields": {
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

When done, you need to re-index your data in order to populate the `motto.raw` sub-field.

And finally, you'll be able to run a query like this, i.e. search on `motto` but aggregate on `motto.raw`:

```
...
"query":{
    "term":{
        "motto":"life"
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "match_count": {
        "terms": { "field": "motto.raw" }
    }
}
...
```